# Can I call a jScript function from url or when an image changes?

Tags: image, url, captcha, jscript

I'm using the free Securimage package for captcha validation in my signup form.

I'm using jScript / AJAX / PHP to check the code while the user types it, and output "incorrect" or "correct" next to the input box and giving it a red border if it's left empty or incorrect.

**The issue here is**: if the user first enter the correct key, then for some reason clicks the "select another image" url the key will change but the input box will not change and therefore not be validated and this might confuse the user to think that the right key is entered when it has actually changed and should be re-entered.

The check captcha function is invoked when something is typed in the captcha input box (keyup) or when done typing (blur). The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var chckcaptcha = function()
    {
        var captcha = encodeURIComponent($("#captcha").val());
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "lib_ajax/somescript.php",
            data: "captcha="+ captcha,
            success: function(msg_captcha)
            {
                $("#status_captcha").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                {
                    // ... some validation code here
                });
            }
        });
    }
    $("#captcha").bind('keyup',chckcaptcha)
    $("#captcha").blur(chckcaptcha);
});
```

The image:

```
<img src="/lib_class/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" name="captcha_img" width="100%" height="100" id="captcha_img" />
```

The refresh url:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = '/lib_class/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">refresh image</a>
```

I need a way to invoke the check captcha function in the jScript when that url is clicked, or when the new image is created. I have absolutely no clue on how to do this.

I have already tried (among many other things) to add this to the jScript:

```
$("#captcha_img").change(chckcaptcha);
```

But that didn't help. Any tips to a solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer didn't work but gave me an idea to a solution. This worked for me...

Function:

```
function refreshImage()
{
    // New image
    document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = 
    '/lib_class/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random();
    // New validation
    chckcaptcha();
}
```

Refresh link:

```
<a href="#" id="refresh-link" onClick="refreshImage(); return false">refresh image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the chckcaptcha function and the function that refreshes the image outside the document ready handler, and then call them in succession when the image is refreshed?

```
    <a href="#" id="refresh-link">refresh image</a>
        ...        


        function chckcaptcha()
            {
                var captcha = encodeURIComponent($("#captcha").val());
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "lib_ajax/somescript.php",
                    data: "captcha="+ captcha,
                    success: function(msg_captcha)
                    {
                        $("#status_captcha").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            // ... some validation code here
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#refresh-link").click(function() { 
document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = '/lib_class/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random();

                chckcaptcha();
            });
            $("#captcha").bind('keyup',chckcaptcha);
            $("#captcha").blur(chckcaptcha);
        });
```

Comment: Doesn' work. The page reloads itself (index.php -> index.php#) but the image don't refresh at all and the captcha is not validated.

Comment: Did you copy paste the code? I'm sure it wouldn't work - I didn't test it, I was merely suggesting an approach =P. How about this?

Comment: I've added a working answer now. You actually pointed me in the right direction, however the link still needed an onclick with a return false in it to stop the page from reloading and just refresh the image+validation...